# How can I create a CSS Progress bar with HOLLOW chevrons?

Tags: css

I need to create a chevron style progress bar which I can do with solids but I would like to only have the active step solid and the inactive steps hollow. How can I do this? This is what I have so far. Any ideas how can I accomplish this?

```
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='step'></div>
  <div class='step'></div>
  <div class='step'></div>
  <div class='step'></div>
</div>
```

```
.grid {
  width: 660px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}


.step {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: #002453;
  color: white;
}

.step:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid white;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
.step:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid #002453;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

Above is a short example. Here is my Fiddle for the full CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/6h1L87wm/4/

Comment: Hi, could you describe what an 'inactive' step is versus an active one as I'm not clear how this is changed/signalled. Thanks.

Comment: For example inactive would be just an outline while active would be a solid fill. Right now if you look at my fiddle it is all solid fill. I am wondering if I have to use SVGs :-/

Comment: active would be my current step in the progress. If I can lock down the CSS I can control everything with JQuery. It's the inactive CSS representation that I am having a problem with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is just put a border around the grid that matches the arrows. I also changed the display to flex and set the justification to `space-between` to ensure the arrows go from start to finish.

```css
.grid {
  width: 660px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #002453;
}

/* ----- step1 ----- */
.step1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: #002453;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: white;
}

.step1:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid #002453;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
/* ----- /step1 ----- */
/* ----- step2----- */
.step2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: #002453;
  color: white;
}

.step2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid white;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
.step2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid #002453;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
/* ----- /step2----- */
/* ----- step3---- */
.step3{
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: #002453;
  color: white;
}

.step3:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid white;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
.step3:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid #002453;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
/* ----- /step3---- */
/* ----- step4 ----- */
.step4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: #002453;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  color: white;
}
.step4:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid white;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
/* ----- /step4 ----- */
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='step1'></div>
  <div class='step2'></div>
  <div class='step3'></div>
  <div class='step4'></div>
</div>
```